# Can you have a strong milky coffee?

Tags: british-english

At work today a debate got rather heated between myself and a colleague, so I've turned to stack overflow.

He says that if you have a lot coffee and a lot of milk its a strong milky coffee.

My argument is that a milky coffee cannot be strong as they are contradicting terms. If you have a lot of both it is just a large coffee.

Comment: I drink espresso macchiato/Cortado. That is an espresso with a drop of milk. It is very strong. Someone might call it milky, but to me, milky means a LOT more milk than coffee.

Comment: While I don't really like this Collins definition of _milky_ 'of or containing milk', it certainly would allow strong coffee with a little milk to be called milky. The following Google Dictionary definition 'containing or mixed with a large amount of milk' is, I'd say, more normally what people have in mind. But even this does not rule out coffee made with just milk, no water, and a lot of coffee extract (instant powder, or a long infusion) being labelled 'strong milky coffee'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Strong* is a measure of how much coffee oils and solids are suspended in the water after the coffee is brewed. *Milky* is a measure of how much milk is added to the brewed coffee.

Coffee can be both *milky* and *strong*. Think espresso with enough milk to make it appear light. But at some point, the milk would dilute the strength of the coffee to the point that the strength was not noticeable.

Comment: Surely it's the ratio of coffee to *liquid* which is important? An ounce of soluble coffee in 7oz of water might be considered strong. An ounce of coffee in 7oz of hot milk would be strong and milky.

Comment: @Andrew: I have one cup every morning - made with two spoonfuls of instant coffee, which most people consider "strong". I've never counted how many such cups I get out of each 100gm jar, but it must be dozens. A whole *ounce* would be more than a quarter of the jar - at those concentrations I think it might simply not be *possible* to dissolve even the most expensive purified soluble coffee.

Comment: @F I did wonder whether that solution would be super-saturated; I couldn't remember how much an ounce was! In which case "might be considered strong" is typical British litotes.